# Unable to output the root token and unseal keys obtained while initializing vault using kubernetes_job_v1

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-cloud

I have a terraform stack which will deploy vault-consul on Google Kubernetes Engine. Now, I need to automate the vault initialization instead of doing it manually using "vault operator init".

So, created a kubernetes_job_v1 resource which will initialize the vault using /v1/sys/init Vault API endpoint. Additionally, I added few things like, if the initialization is successful, a kubernetes secret should be created out of the json output got while initializing which contains root_token and unseal_keys of the vault. And if the initialization is not successful, the job should get restarted and retry to initialize the vault.

Below is my kubernetes job

```
resource "kubernetes_job_v1" "create_secret_job" {
  metadata {
    name = "init-vault"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace_v1.helper.metadata[0].name
  }
  spec {
    ttl_seconds_after_finished = 1200
    template {
      metadata {
        name = "init-vault"
      }
      spec {
        service_account_name = kubernetes_service_account_v1.init_vault.metadata[0].name
        container {
          name  = "init-vault"
          image = "ubuntu"
          command = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args = [
            <<-EOT
            apt-get update -y && apt-get install jq -y && apt-get install curl -y && apt-get install -y telnet && \
            curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && \
            chmod +x kubectl && mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/ && kubectl version && mkdir /mnt/secret && \
            cd /mnt/secret && echo '{"recovery_shares": 5, "recovery_threshold": 3, "stored_shares": 5}' > payload.json && \
            curl -k --request PUT --data @payload.json https://vault-0.vault-internal.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/sys/init > output.json && \
            curl -k --request GET --data @payload.json https://vault-0.vault-internal.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/sys/init > getresponse.json && \
            cat getresponse.json && \
            initialized_value=$(jq -r '.initialized' getresponse.json); \
            if [ "$initialized_value" = "true" ]; then \
              echo 'Vault is initialized'; \
              kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=/mnt/secret/output.json; \
              exit 0; \
            else \
              echo 'Vault is not initialized. Restarting the job...'; \
              exit 1; \
            fi
          
            EOT
          ]
        }
        restart_policy = "Never"
      }
    }
    backoff_limit = 10
  }
  wait_for_completion = true
}
```

Now, I need to provide the content of output.json in terraform output.

Tried with below

```
data "kubernetes_secret_v1" "my_secret" {
  metadata {
    name      = "my-secret"
    namespace = "helper"
  }
  depends_on = [ kubernetes_job_v1.create_secret_job ]
}

output "my_secret_data" {
  value = data.kubernetes_secret_v1.my_secret.data["output.json"]
}
```

But it's returning error as it has nothing except null value.

I am using terraform cloud to create the k8s stack. As per my understanding, terraform is unable to understand about the resource which is not created using terraform resource "kubernetes_secret". Got stucked at how to display the secret data on terraform output.

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in Advance!